# Get product price in html module opencart 2.x

Tags: variables, module, opencart

Im beginner in opencart developing, and now i need something pretty simple ( as i think...) im using opencart 2.1.0.1 and i made a simple table

```
<table align="left" border="1" cellspacing="1" style="table-layout:fixed;width:500px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>here i want the product price</td>
        <td>here i want the prduct price</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to get the product price in the data cells(and maybe to make some operations with it later on the backend).
Is it possible by making a html module, or i need to put my code directly on my .tpl page and use the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Given the feedback on my original answer, the updated response is below:
You can access the price by using `$price` but this will contain the currency so you can insert the code below on the tpl file before your table:

```
<?php 
    $pricenew = $product['price'];
    $pricenew  = preg_replace( '/\D/', '', $pricenew  );
?>
```

Now you can use `$pricenew` on your table as your formula requires it.

**Original Answer:**
Assuming you're creating an extension for the OpenCart install, you will need to have both a controller and a view (.tpl file) at the very least, best practises would encourage you to include a language file to make translation simpler. You may not require a model if you're just displaying certain products.

I would suggest reading [this](http://docs.opencart.com/developer/module/) from the OpenCart documentation, there are also tutorials that make learning OpenCart extension development simpler. [Here's a tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-plugin-in-opencart-21xx-part-one--cms-26155) on making an extension that displays recent products.

Comment: The job is more simple tham creating a new module, i just want to show a table with prices on the product page, which table i will make with html/bootstrap, just i cant pass the price variables...

Comment: I want to get the clear (without currency formatting) price, make some estimations for leasing plans (i have a clear formula about this) and put this prices on the table cells

Comment: Ok, if you only want to play around with information already on the product page I can give you some php code that strips the formatting from the price and gives you a new php variable to use how you like. Will this help? I will update the answer if that's what you need

Comment: Yes! Thats all i need! I just want to have the integer price on the product .tpl page, thats everything